# Influxdb select data from a specific shard

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I would like to know if it is possible somehow from the CLI of the influx to select the data of a specific shard. I also would like to select the series within two timestamps but i haven't yet found how. Any input would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** I would like to know if it possible somehow from the CLI of the influx to select the data of a specific shard.

**A:** At influxdb 1.3 this is not possible. However you should be able to work out what data lives in there.

Query to get the shards information:

`show shards`

it should tell you the `start` and `end` date time of the data (across all **series** in the database) contained in that `shard`.

**For instance**

Given Shard info:

```
id  database  retention_policy shard_group start_time           end_time             expiry_time          owners
--  --------  ---------------- ----------- ----------           --------             -----------          ------
123 mydb      autogen          123         2012-11-26T00:00:00Z 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z
124 mydb      autogen          124         2013-01-14T00:00:00Z 2013-01-21T00:00:00Z 2013-01-21T00:00:00Z
125 mydb      autogen          125         2013-04-29T00:00:00Z 2013-05-06T00:00:00Z 2013-05-06T00:00:00Z
```

Given Measurements:

```
name: measurements
name
----
measurement_abc
measurement_def
measurement_123
```

`Shard` 123 will contain all of the data across the noted measurements above that fall in the start time of `2012-11-26T00:00:00Z` and end time of `2012-12-03T00:00:00Z`. That is, running a `drop shard 123` would see data in that range disappearing across the measurements.